# How to add a library using gradle on IntelliJ?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, gradle, spring-boot

I want to use Vmeo's API on my Spring Boot application. For that, I visited the [the Vimeo API authentication page](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication), which requires this [this OAuth](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java/releases) library for authentication. I found their documentation quite confusing for a newbie.

I've have downloaded and installed [sdkman](http://sdkman.io/) and [gradle](https://gradle.org/install). And of course downloaded the [.zip](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java/archive/v1.1.0-release.zip) from the mentioned library.

My project uses maven currently. What should I do from here ? How can I add it into my project ?

EDIT:

I'm getting really frustrating with this.. I can't access, found the `com.vimeo.*` package. Here is how my project is setup on IntelliJ:

[image]

Comment: maven and gradle are both project build and package management tools, which one are you using?
you just need to find the vimeo packages and add it in the dependency in the maven or gradle setting files

Comment: Yeah, I would like to keep using Maven, if possible. How do I add this library into my project path with IntelliJ ?

Comment: I don't know much about Vimeo Api, for oauth, maybe check this https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/ . It shows which libs you should include in your pom.xml. Hope that helps

Comment: Attach screenshot of your project structure if possible.

Comment: @PratikAmbani I've attached a screenshot into my question, please take a look.

Comment: @Simon, Thank for the suggestion. However, I would like to use Vimeo library, 'cause its a request that came to me.

Answer (score 1):

The Vimeo Networking Java code that you have shown in your screen shot is built using gradle and we recommend that you include it using a gradle dependency. Since you aren't using gradle, however, you should be able to include it within a maven project like so:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.vimeo.networking</groupId>
  <artifactId>vimeo-networking</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

It is hosted on Bintray here: https://bintray.com/vimeo/maven/vimeo-networking

Comment: Kevin, I've create a new project and tried to use your suggestion from Bintray, however, I'm having the same issue with. I've commited and pushed it into GitHub: https://github.com/valterhenrique/42712011